Coding in R. How do I select based on if a Boolean is true for a row when the the Boolean needs to check across multiple columns?
My data set looks something like this:



Movie Name
Action
Thriller
Horror
MovieBudget




Movie1
0
1
1
2500000


Movie2
1
0
0
3430000


Movie3
1
0
1
1240000



I am trying to find which genre has the highest budget. For example, in the example dataset the film with the highest MovieBudget is Movie 2. Ideally, I would get that information outputted like:
I am trying to find which genre has the highest budget. For example, in the example dataset the film with the highest MovieBudget is Movie 2. Ideally, I would get that information outputted like:



Movie Name
Movie Budget
Action




Movie#2
3430000
1



If it was a film that had two genres then there would be an additional column for that second genre.
The dataset I am working with has a lot more genres so I can't manually call each one every time I need them.
I've attemped by setting a general variable with all the genre categories equaling 1 but that didn't work.
bool<- raw_data |> c(Crime!=0, Drama!=0, Western!=0, Biography!=0, History!=0, Adventure!=0, Fantasy!=0, Mystery!=0, SciFi!=0, Romance!=0, Thriller!=0, War!=0, Family!=0, Animation!=0, Comedy!=0)

raw_data |> slice_max(InflatedBudget) |> select(FilmName, Year, InflatedBudget, InflatedGross, raw_data[bool])

When I use the code above I get:
Error: object 'Crime' not found
I don't have much experience with R so I'm not quite sure where to even start.

In general,  evaluate the boolean columns with something like product(my_table[,c(2:(ncol(my_table)-1)]  will save a lot of code and time.

Since you're using dplyr in your example here's a tidyverse approach. Also works if more movies have the same maximum value.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, -c(MovieName, MovieBudget)) %>% 
  slice_max(MovieBudget) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider()
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MovieName MovieBudget Action
  <chr>           <int>  <int>
1 Movie2        3430000      1

Data
df <- structure(list(MovieName = c("Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3"), 
    Action = c(0L, 1L, 1L), Thriller = c(1L, 0L, 0L), Horror = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L), MovieBudget = c(2500000L, 3430000L, 1240000L)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


I've got other columns that use booleans too though. I received an error message stating that it couldn't pivot_wider() due to two columns. @Andre Wildberg

If there are other columns first thing you can try is to also exclude those in the first pivot_longer step within the -c(…)

In your example you probably could try something like below
> (u <- subset(df, MovieBudget == max(MovieBudget)))[which(u != 0)]
  MovieName Action MovieBudget
2    Movie2      1     3430000


Where would that go though? Would 'u' be a replacement for my variable bool in my attempt? @ThomasIsCoding
